# Why is this use of Bitmap faster?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, bitmap

In my project I have two different classes which needs to parse a Bitmap. The classes parses the Bitmaps identically apart from one thing, one parser clips the Bitmap, removing parts of the image while the other does not. What I noticed was a remarkable speed difference between the two parsers. I found the reason being that in the fast parser I use

```
Bitmap b = originalBitmap.Clone(clipBounds, originalBitmap.PixelFormat);
```

and then process b. I tried adding just the clone part to the slow parser with no effect. However editing the original image to be 1 pixel wider and then cutting away that width with Clone() made the slow parser just as fast and the fast one. The difference is 500 ms vs ~20 ms, measured with Stopwatch.

How does the use of `Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle rect, PixelFormat format)` make the parser so much faster?

Full code:
(Previously slow parser)

```
private void parseImage(string file, Size tileSize) {

        Console.WriteLine("Parsing palette (Single Threaded)...");
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Bitmap bmp = TextureLoader.LoadTexture(file, TextureLoader.TextureType.Palette);

        //Cutting away the added 1 pixel width (161 to 160 wide)
        bmp = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 1024),bmp.PixelFormat);

        int tilesWide = bmp.Width / tileSize.Width;
        int tilesHigh = bmp.Height / tileSize.Height;
        tiles = new Bitmap[tilesWide * tilesHigh];
        int tileID = 0;

        Rectangle cloneRect;
        for (int y = 0; y < tilesHigh; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < tilesWide; x++) {
                cloneRect = new Rectangle(x * tileSize.Width, y * tileSize.Height, tileSize.Width, tileSize.Height);
                tiles[tileID++] = bmp.Clone(cloneRect, bmp.PixelFormat);
            }
        }
        NumTiles = tileID;
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\t-- Finished parsing palette. Loaded {0} tiles in {1} ms", tileID, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Fast parser:

```
private void parseSheet(string file, Vector2 spriteSize, Rectangle clip) {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting parse of spritesheet: {0}", file);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Bitmap bmp = TextureLoader.LoadTexture(file, TextureLoader.TextureType.Sprite);
        bmp = bmp.Clone(clip, bmp.PixelFormat);

        _spriteTileSize = spriteSize;
        _numTiles = new Size(
            (int)(bmp.Width / spriteSize.X),
            (int)(bmp.Height / spriteSize.Y)
            );
        _spriteTiles = new Bitmap[_numTiles.Width * _numTiles.Height];

        Rectangle r;
        int tileID = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < _numTiles.Height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < _numTiles.Width; x++) {
                r = new Rectangle((int)(x * spriteSize.X), (int)(y * spriteSize.Y), (int)(spriteSize.X), (int)(spriteSize.Y));
                _spriteTiles[tileID++] = bmp.Clone(r, bmp.PixelFormat);
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\t-- Finnished parsing. Loaded {0} sprite tiles in {1} ms", tileID, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the full fast and slow versions of one of these instead of two fast versions, please? It makes testing easier. =)

Comment: Commenting out the line ´bmp = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 1024),bmp.PixelFormat);´ restores it to the slow version. That's the only difference.

Comment: Do the versions perform the same when the image is 160×1024 as when it’s 161×1024?

Comment: As I said in the question, that had no effect. It seems the Clone() actually has to modify the image.

Comment: If you make the image 162×1024 and clip it to 161×1024, what happens?

Comment: this is one of those problems that gets fixed some time and you have no idea what just happened. then you realize you cant even reproduce the problem xD

Comment: going from 162 to 161 causes the parser to still be fast

Comment: If you run it on Mono, do you see the same behaviour? Windows GDI+ isn’t open-source so it’s hard to say for sure what’s going on with it.